# Installation Root (Cern) v6.00.02 with Cygwin

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin, root

I have installed Root (Cern).

Before calling "root" it is necessary starting the X server (by Cygwin, typing "startx"), to allow Root to use Windows.

By `setup-x86_64.exe` I installed Cygwin (approximately 50 GB of HD)
and I chose "install" for all packages;

I fear, however, there is something else to install, because by giving the command `startx` reports the error:

```
gnome-session: PID 3552: WARNING: Could not connect to ConsoleKit: Failed to connect to
socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory";
```

In fact the folder "dbus" is missing.

1. What's missing?
2. what are the essential things to install ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install:

dbus-x11 and dbus

The list of available packages on cygwin is here

https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

PS: use startxwin instead of startx